# ssas- how to create calculated measure with logical calculation/computation?

Tags: ssas, olap-cube

I have a measure(say XX) for a fact but its aggregation type is sum. Now i want to perform a logical case on that i.e if the value of that measure XX is greater than 0 show one else show 0. If I do this with IIF or Case  in cube or in excel using olap pivot table extn , I am getting the dim value (against which I will browse this measure) repeatedly / multiple times.
If I use null instead of 0 in IIF or case , I could get the calue but grand total is not shown properly. Also I want that measure XX to act as normal other measures i.e I should be able to browse it against other dims also.
i used the formula available in olap pivot table extension IIF(xx > 0 , 0, 1) (iif(condition , false_val, true_val)) but it causes repetition of dim so i tried iif(xx>0 , 1, null) but can not browse this against multiple dims (same is with case when then end also).
I also tried OLAP pivot table calculation with count and filter function but this is also not giving me desired results. Other approach tried was creating a calculation in cube itself but this also causes the dim populating repeatedly problem . Please let me know if there is some other approach available.

Comment: Can you show the code that you used to define the calculated measure?

Comment: In StackOverflow, it is preferred that you edit your question instead of putting clarifications into comments, as this makes reading the question more easy for future users who have similar problems.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "getting the dim value (against which I will browse this measure) repeatedly / multiple times": Does the table show rows A, B, C before you add the measure, and A, B, C, A, B, C, C, A, B, B, B after you added it?

Comment: About dim repetition , yes, what you said is correct. And the repetition count for each dim = no of entries of that dim which I have in my fact